# Google visualization - table data not rendered

Tags: ajax, json, spring-mvc, google-visualization

I am struggling with google visualization api. I have defined following Spring controller that returns json representation of com.google.visualization.datasource.datatable.DataTable.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/magento", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = { "Accept=application/json" }, params = { "table" }, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    public @ResponseBody
    DataTable getMagentoCustomersTable() {
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        ArrayList<ColumnDescription> cd = new ArrayList<ColumnDescription>();
        cd.add(new ColumnDescription("customerId", ValueType.TEXT,
                "Customer Id"));
        cd.add(new ColumnDescription("email", ValueType.TEXT, "Email"));
        cd.add(new ColumnDescription("firstName", ValueType.TEXT, "First Name"));
        cd.add(new ColumnDescription("lastName", ValueType.TEXT, "Last Name"));

        data.addColumns(cd);

        // Fill the data table.
        try {
            for (CustomerInterface customer : magentoService.getCustomers()
                    .getCustomers()) {
                data.addRowFromValues(customer.getCustomerId(),
                        customer.getEmail(), customer.getFirstName(),
                        customer.getLastName());
            }
        } catch (TypeMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid type!");
        }

        return data;
    }
```

Then I am using following ajax call to produce Table output

```
$.ajax({
            url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/customer/magento.json",
            data : {
                table : null
            },
            dataType : 'json'
        }).success(
                function(response) {
                    // Create the data table.
                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(response);

                    // Set chart options
                    var options = {
                        'title' : 'Magento Customers',
                        'width' : 400,
                        'height' : 300
                    };

                    // Instantiate and draw our table, passing in some options.
                    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document
                            .getElementById('chart_div'));

                    table.draw(data, options);
                });
```

Ajax call return valid json object with data. Table is created with expected number of rows, there is no error in processing js but all table rows are empty as well as column headers.
So my question is am I missing something? What could went wrong?

==EDIT==
Below you can see sample json returned from ajax call to client. When this json is passed to DataTable constructor it is created  but I noticed that no columns are created in DataTable object whereas rows are.

```
{
    "warnings": [],
    "rows": [{
        "customProperties": {},
        "cells": [{
            "value": {
                "value": "1",
                "type": "TEXT",
                "null": false,
                "objectToFormat": "1"
            },
            "type": "TEXT",
            "null": false,
            "customProperties": {},
            "formattedValue": null
        }, {
            "value": {
                "value": "lname1@gmail.com",
                "type": "TEXT",
                "null": false,
                "objectToFormat": "lname1@gmail.com"
            },
            "type": "TEXT",
            "null": false,
            "customProperties": {},
            "formattedValue": null
        }, {
            "value": {
                "value": "fname1",
                "type": "TEXT",
                "null": false,
                "objectToFormat": "fname1"
            },
            "type": "TEXT",
            "null": false,
            "customProperties": {},
            "formattedValue": null
        }, {
            "value": {
                "value": "lname1",
                "type": "TEXT",
                "null": false,
                "objectToFormat": "lname1"
            },
            "type": "TEXT",
            "null": false,
            "customProperties": {},
            "formattedValue": null
        }]
    }, {
        "customProperties": {},
        "cells": [{
            "value": {
                "value": "2",
                "type": "TEXT",
                "null": false,
                "objectToFormat": "2"
            },
            "type": "TEXT",
            "null": false,
            "customProperties": {},
            "formattedValue": null
        }, {
            "value": {
                "value": "lname2@gmail.com",
                "type": "TEXT",
                "null": false,
                "objectToFormat": "lname2@gmail.com"
            },
            "type": "TEXT",
            "null": false,
            "customProperties": {},
            "formattedValue": null
        }, {
            "value": {
                "value": "fname1",
                "type": "TEXT",
                "null": false,
                "objectToFormat": "fname1"
            },
            "type": "TEXT",
            "null": false,
            "customProperties": {},
            "formattedValue": null
        }, {
            "value": {
                "value": "lname2",
                "type": "TEXT",
                "null": false,
                "objectToFormat": "lname2"
            },
            "type": "TEXT",
            "null": false,
            "customProperties": {},
            "formattedValue": null
        }]
    }],
    "numberOfRows": 2,
    "numberOfColumns": 4,
    "columnDescriptions": [{
        "id": "customerId",
        "type": "TEXT",
        "pattern": "",
        "customProperties": {},
        "label": "Customer Id"
    }, {
        "id": "email",
        "type": "TEXT",
        "pattern": "",
        "customProperties": {},
        "label": "Email"
    }, {
        "id": "firstName",
        "type": "TEXT",
        "pattern": "",
        "customProperties": {},
        "label": "First Name"
    }, {
        "id": "lastName",
        "type": "TEXT",
        "pattern": "",
        "customProperties": {},
        "label": "Last Name"
    }],
    "customProperties": {},
    "localeForUserMessages": null
}
```

Comment: wasn't it much simpler to create an object with this values as an array list and to add all values as object properties for each customer in part? and on client to use directly json as data type? and on client to get all the data from json?

Comment: do not know if it would be that much simpler, surely I know there are more ways to populate DataTable but what I was curious about is why data from DataTable are not rendered as expected when using current approach

Comment: Try to debug/log it to see what happens after all. I suspect to start from: data.addRowFromValues(...) or cause there is incompatible the server side generated data with the expected one on client

Comment: Update your question with a sample of the JSON returned by the AJAX call to your data source.

Comment: check updates in question text